# c#: How to Post async request and get stream with httpclient?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, stream, httpclient

I need to send async request to the server and get the information from the response stream. 
I'm using HttpClient.GetStreamAsync(), but the server response that POST should be used. Is there a similar method like PostStreamAsync()? Thank you.

Answer (score 25):

If you want to use `HttpClient` for streaming large data then you should not use `PostAsync` cause `message.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync` would read the entire stream into memory.  Instead you can use the following code block.

```
var message = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "http://localhost:3100/api/test");
var response = await client.SendAsync(message, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead);
var stream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
```

The key thing here is the `HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead` option which tells the client not to read the entire content into memory.

Comment: If you need to add content to the POST request you can add it like that:
var request = new HttpRequestMessage { Method = HttpMethod.Post, RequestUri = new Uri(apiUrl), Content = content };

Answer (score 2):

Use `HttpClient.PostAsync` and you can get the response stream via `HttpResponseMessage.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync()` method.

```
var message = await client.PostAsync(url, content);
var stream = await message.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
```

Comment: Note that this will read the entire stream into memory. Which is mostly not what users expect when they plan to use streaming.

Answer (score -2):

Instead of HttpClient, maybe you should use [HttpWebRequest](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.net.httpwebrequest(v=vs.110).aspx) ?

They offer both async method and the possibility to switch between post and get by setting their `method` property.

e.g:

```
var request = (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create(uri);
request.Method = "POST";
var postStream = await request.GetRequestStreamAsync()
```