# Download Zip file with Webclient c# with POST method

Tags: c#

I have build an API which gives output in zip file when more than one file is requested
Now I have to download this zip file in C# WPF app.

**To access API, we have to use POST ( instead of GET ) and JSON parameters.**

I am able to download one file as string with help of below code

```
  WebClient client = new WebClient();

 var vm = new { from = "A", to = "S", files= "all", type = "csv", file = "Single" };

 client.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/json";
  var dataString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(vm);

   var response = client.UploadData("https://myurl.com/data", "POST", System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(dataString));
```

But not able to figure out how to download zip file and save it to disk

Comment: Don't use the obsolete WebClient class in the first place. It was only meant to be used for simple scenarios as a component in a Windows Forms screen, never for APIs or complex scenarios. It was fully replaced by HttpClient 10 years ago. `UploadData` returns a byte array with the entire response which means you have to parse it yourself to identify the headers like the content type and file name, and extract the file

Comment: Thanks , i am aware of HttpClient but could not find any success in same :( , But with help of webclient i found partial success , If you can help me with HttpClient then i will be obliged

Comment: Does this answer your question? [c#: How to Post async request and get stream with httpclient?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37067355/c-how-to-post-async-request-and-get-stream-with-httpclient)

Comment: @Eldar , unfortunately no . It seems i have to change API from POST to GET method , then it will be easy for me

Comment: The most voted answer is a sample with post request. Yes it is suggested to use get method but it's doable with post also.

Comment: @eldar, thanks it was very simple. Actually simplest of whole code but somehow i missed it . It is done now with File.WriteAllBytes("results.zip", response);